# Understanding open balls and closed balls for the Post Office metric?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(\mathbb{R},|\cdot|)$ be the metric space consisting of $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard metric. Let $x$ in and $y$ in $\mathbb{R}$, we consider the distance $d$ given by $$d(x,y)=\begin{cases} |x| + |y| &\text{if}\,\,\,\,x\neq y \\ 0 &\text{if}\,\,\,\, x=y \end{cases}$$

with $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $r>0$. Describe the open ball $B(x,r)$ and the closed $B_c(x,r)$ ball with respect to the distance $d$, for the case  $x=0$ and the case $x\neq 0$

My attempt : in case $x=0$, we have  $B(x,r) = \{ y \in \mathbb{R} : |y|   < r\}$ which is the open interval  $]-r, r[$ and $B_c(x,r) = \{ y \in \mathbb{R} : |y|   \leq r\}$ which is the closed interval  $[-r, r]$

but I can't find the case $r<x$ and $r>x$

Any help will be appreciated

thanks you

Comment: Draw the unit circle with respect to the metric. That is the set of points such that $d(0,y)=1$. What does this tell you about the balls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've already covered the $x = 0$ case, let's look at $x \neq 0.$ There are three subcases to consider:

**Subcase 1:** $0 < r < |x|.$

A point $y \in \mathbb{R}$ is in $B_{c}(x, r)$ if and only if $d(x, y) < r.$ If $y = x,$ then $d(x, y) = 0 < r,$ so $x$ is in the closed ball. On the other hand, if $y \neq x,$ then $d(x, y) = |x| + |y| \geq |x| > r,$ so $y$ can't be in the closed ball.

So, in this case, the closed ball $B_{c}(x, r)$ contains the single point $x$. It is clear that the open ball $B(x, r)$ contains $x$ as well, and it can't contain any other points either (because it is a subset of the closed ball).

**Subcase 2:** $|x| = r.$

Once again, note that both the open and closed balls contain $x$. Now, for a point $y \neq x,$ consider the inequalities $d(x, y) = |x| + |y| < r$ and $d(x, y) = |x| + |y| \leq r.$ The first inequality has no solutions, since $|x| = r$. The second inequality has the solution $y = 0$ (note that since $|x| = r,$ $x$ is not equal to $0$, so $x$ and $y =0$ are indeed distinct).

So, in this case, the open ball $B(x, r)$ only contains $x$, but the closed ball $B(x, r)$ contains $x$ and $0.$

**Subcase 3:** $|x| < r$.

As before, the point $x$ is contained in both the open and closed balls. Now, for a point $y \neq x,$ consider the inequalities $d(x, y) = |x| + |y| < r$ and $d(x, y) = |x| + |y| \leq r.$ These two are equivalent to the inequalities $|y| < r - |x|$ and $|y| \leq r - |x|.$

Since $r - |x|$ is greater than $0$, we see the solutions to these inequalities are the open interval $(-r+|x|, r-|x|)$ and the closed interval $[-r+|x|, r-|x|]$, respectively.

So, the open ball $B(x, r)$ is the set $\{x\} \cup (-r+|x|, r-|x|),$ and the closed ball $B_{c}(x, r)$ is the set $\{x\} \cup [-r+|x|, r-|x|].$